# How to use static pthread library in C program (Visual Studio 2008)?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, pthreads, static-libraries, static-linking

I got the following test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pthread.h"


void* test_thread(void *ptr)
{
    printf("In teh thread");
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int foo = 1;
    pthread_t t;

    if (0 != pthread_create(&t, NULL, test_thread, (void *)foo)) {
        printf("This was never going to work.");
    }

    while(1)
        ;

    return 0;
}
```

When building, I'm getting the following errors:

> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_pthread_create referenced in function _main 1>C:\Users\rtt.PROLAN\Downloads\pthread-win32-master\Debug\Majs.exe :
>   fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

I built the static library from this [source](https://github.com/GerHobbelt/pthread-win32). I then added "pthread_lib.lib" to Linker -> Input in the Project properties. And made sure that file was in the lib path.

Any idea what's causing the linker errors?

Comment: pthread.lib.lib looks suspicious.  If that's not a typo in your question, I'd check this really matches the name of the static library.

Comment: On a side note, how about using a real C compiler like `gcc`, instead of microsoft's c compiler which is still C89? With that, such basic libraries as pthread already come with the (almost-)POSIX-compliant gnu libraries.

Comment: pthread.lib.lib was not a typo, it's the original name when building from that source (using the included visual studio project). I've renamed it to pthread.lib but decided not to change anything in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the following line to your application when you're linking statically.

```
#define PTW32_STATIC_LIB
```